# Return both a mutable reference to the container and the found element in a nested find_map

Tags: rust

### Context

Rust Playground Link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1e216604c5f7d7436f4715c90a16acc6

Given some nested containers, I want to get both the element I'm looking for and a mutable reference to the parent container i.e. something like this

```
let (y, value) = t.map
    .iter_mut()
    .find_map(|(_, y)| {
        y.elements.iter().find_map(|x| {
            if x.a != target {
                None
            } else {
                Some((y, x))
            }
        })
    })
    .ok_or("Not found")?;
```

the issue is that I get the following errors

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `y`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:33:27
   |
28 |           .find_map(|(_, y)| {
   |                          - captured outer variable
29 |               y.elements.iter().find_map(|x| {
   |  ________________________________________-
30 | |                 if x.a != target {
31 | |                     None
32 | |                 } else {
33 | |                     Some((y, x))
   | |                           ^ move occurs because `y` has type `&mut Y`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
34 | |                 }
35 | |             })
   | |_____________- captured by this `FnMut` closure

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `y` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:29:40
   |
29 |             y.elements.iter().find_map(|x| {
   |             ----------------- -------- ^^^ move out of `y` occurs here
   |             |                 |
   |             |                 borrow later used by call
   |             borrow of `y.elements` occurs here
...
33 |                     Some((y, x))
   |                           - move occurs due to use in closure
```

### Questions

I'm wondering two things

- First and foremost, what's the idiomatic way to write what I'm trying to achieve without getting errors?
- Second, I'm not too experienced with closures and I don't really know where/how the specified moves are happening. Can someone explain?

Comment: This is not possible. Rust's borrowing rules were designed to intentionally prevent mutating your parent object while the child reference is still available. You'll need to rethink how you access and mutate your data. Considering your example always creates a new `X` from the child reference, returning a clone would avoid this issue.

Comment: Nitpick: you can replace `iter_mut()` with `values_mut()`.

Comment: What kmdreko said is spot on. To look at it a different way, Rust strictly prohibits you from having two mutable references to the same value. If you have a mutable reference to a container and one of its values at the same time, you could obtain a second mutable reference to the same value through the reference to the container. Another issue is that nothing would prevent you from invoking `.clear()` on the container reference -- now where does the reference-to-child point?

Answer (score 0):

Rust playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=94836d06d78ff7347a3adbc4fd319b3f

Not sure if this is optimal, but here is how I figured out how to get it to compile. Instead of returning references, I returned the (cloned) key into the `HashMap` and the index into the `Vec`

```
let (key, index) = t.map
    .iter()
    .find_map(|(key, y)| {
        y.elements.iter().enumerate().find_map(|(i, x)| {
            if x.a != target {
                None
            } else {
                Some((key.clone(), i))
            }
        })
    })
    .ok_or("Not found")?;
```

That way I wouldn't actually hold any references to the data I was looking for, but would still know exactly how to access it.